# Code formatting with Stack Overflow, Programmers and Code Review

Tags: support, code-formatting

My eyes are destroyed, so I'm using a screen reader. Whenever I post some codes to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), I always got some comments about my code formatting not being readable and indented even when pressing "ctrl+k".

I discussed this problem with a user in chat and he keeps telling me to click something to format my code. I forgot what it is but I remember it contains {} or something like that. However I really can't find it so I assume that is an image and he confirmed it. How can I correctly format my code here? Is there another way without clicking that image? Many questions I posted got edited because the users say my code is unreadable.

I'm using eclipse and it has a feature "correct indentation" which I think formats my code but it seems to be not working because of the edits to my codes here.

I will try @Martijn Pieters instructions. I will use a simple c++ code. I added 4 extra spaces in each line of the code.

The include directive, the main declaration and the closing brace doesn't have any spaces when I coppied from eclipse.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int *crash = nullptr;
    std::cout << *crash << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is this correct?

edit: I made a longer code. Just to make sure I got it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "SALES_DATA.h"

int main() {
    Sales_data data1, data2;
    double price = 0;
    std::cin >> data1.bookNo >> data1.unitsSold >> price;
    data1.revenue = data1.unitsSold*price;
    std::cin >> data2.bookNo >> data2.unitsSold >> price;
    data2.revenue = data2.unitsSold*price;
    if (data1.bookNo == data2.bookNo) {
        unsigned totalCount = data1.unitsSold+data2.unitsSold;
        double totalRevenue = data1.revenue+data2.revenue;
        std::cout << data1.bookNo << " " << totalCount << " " << totalRevenue << " ";
        if (totalCount != 0) {
            std::cout << totalRevenue/totalCount << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "(no sales)" << std::endl;
        }
        return 0;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Data must refer to the same ISBN" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Is this totally correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the code button uses an image. It does have a tooltip, your screenreader may be able to identify it to you as `Code Sample <pre><code> Ctrl+K`.

Code blocks are marked up by indentation. In Eclipse you can add 4 spaces extra indentation to the whole block, and those 4 spaces then cause the block to be interpreted as code (including syntax highlighting).

That is exactly what the button does; if you have selected *whole lines* in the editor, the button (or pressing <kbd>CTRL+K</kbd> adds 4 spaces at the start of each of the selected lines. If there are already are 4 spaces at the start of every selected line, the reverse happens.

If text that is not a complete line (so a single word, or several words) is selected, backticks (`` ` ``) are put around the selected text. This renders the selected text as code inline, without syntax highlighting. Use this for variable names, object types, etc.; anything code related.

The code block in your [first post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56167/inserting-tables-with-foreign-key) on code review was marked up correctly, albeit that *within* the code block there was no indentation of the code itself.

Comment: Isn't an extra alternative to enclose the code in an opening `<code>` and closing `</code>` tag?

Comment: @rene: Then you don't get the right formatting. No syntax highlighting, lines are wrapped, and the changed background color applies to the text, not the block. In other words, ugly.

Comment: @rene it also needs `<pre>` tags then

Comment: @3ventic: and even then the resulting layout is odd.

Comment: How is it odd in [this test](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233794/158100)? @MartijnPieters

Comment: @rene: Normally, you'd nest `<pre>` and `<code>` the other way around. Note the extra newlines however around the code. Even if you remove all whitespace between the first line and the opening `<code><pre>` tags you get a dangling 'grey block'.

Comment: OK, I accept that. Leaves open why hitting ctrl+K doesn't work for the OP. It does for me...

Comment: @rene: I can imagine being legally blind and using a screenreader makes it a lot harder to select the correct set of lines to indent them.

Comment: That problem doesn't change with trying to find the right tooltip in the menu. That was the reason I hoped an *inline* solution would be available.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters
 pleas check the code in my edit

Comment: Do you mean the button and ctrl+k do the same thing? But people still edit my codes even though I always use ctrl+k.

Comment: @wormUser: The block you added is formatted correctly, yes.

Comment: @wormUser: Yes, the button and CTRL+K do the same thing. The keyboard combination is a shortcut for the button. The editing on the one post I saw was just to add some *more* formatting; you did nothing wrong but someone thought the post would look better *still* with some additional editing.

Comment: Ok, what about my another question. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52194/mvc-controller-code. The code has already been correctly formatted by other users. But if you can see the previous revisions of the post, what's wrong with my first code formatting in the question?

Comment: @wormUser: Yes, I can see you were struggling with the formatting; not until revision 4 did you get anything resembling a code block working. Another user saw that you initially had more indentation in your code and made a suggested edit that better reflected your original code formatting.

Comment: @wormUser: your 4th revision had 4 spaces at the start of every line, but the original indentation of the code was lost entirely. Everything displayed as having no indentation.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters
 I added another code. Please check the format just to make sure I got it right.

Comment: @wormUser: looks great to me!

Comment: So all in all, I will let eclipse handle the correct indentations, then add four spaces at each line of code or use ctrl+k when I paste it in SO?

Comment: @wormUser exactly. In addition, perhaps post a standard comment below the post explaining you are visually impaired and apologise for any formatting mistakes, or something. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that the HTML code is wrong. This is the “button” for formatting:

```
<li class="wmd-button" style="left: 125px;" id="wmd-code-button" title="Code Sample <pre><code> Ctrl+K">
  <span style="background-position: -80px 0px;"></span>
</li>
```

It is neither a button nor a link, so you can not access it per keyboard easily. The `span` element should be a button with text or at least an `aria-labelledby` attribute.

Comment: Um, but why didn't they made it a button or a link?