# Disable the default TAB key behavior in chat

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat, keyboard

Currently, TAB in chat has one purpose, name completion. You type <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> and it would complete to `@SecondRikudo`, awesome.

But there's a problem, TAB's default behavior is to change focus to another input, incidentally, the next input is the submit button for chat (the [send](/questions/tagged/send) button).

This is a problem when the tab completion doesn't resolve, or is too slow to respond, because if you mispelled <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> and instead typed <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>, the result would be that you type `@sr`, and then move away to the send button. From now on, three things might happen:

- You may notice the error, an <kbd>SHIFT+TAB</kbd> back to the textarea (or use the mouse) to correct the error, and keep on chatting.
- You hit backspace, in which case you would actually be pressing the back button in the browser.
- You hit space, which would send your errorenous `@sr` to the room.

In light of this, I want to suggest to disable TAB's default behavior as a navigational key, only when focus is found on the textarea.

Comment: Just don't hurry when typing :p

Comment: Please don't take my tab-navigation away from me.

Comment: I *actually make use of this*. Do **not** remove the tab behaviour, please.

Comment: Please post an answer with your usecase so that it can be debated and voted on separately, it's hard to do it in a comment. @MartijnPieters

Comment: How about a different name completion key, like a space for example?

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett That's also possible, but developers are generally used to TAB completion from the various dev tools we have (prime example, Terminal).

Comment: I can't help but think I'd encounter this a lot less if  ɥʇǝS would spell his name using proper characters.

Answer (score 4):

Just like [my response to the same request for the Markdown editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161706/115866): No. The Tab key is the most important accessibility key; I would judge it to be on the very top of the list of keys that you should leave alone in a web page. Even overriding it for autocompletion was a borderline decision, and it's okay *only* because those situations in which the Tab key does not have its native functionality are a) rare, b) obvious, and c) easy to end.

What I *could* live with is adding a second autocomplete key (combination), if there's consensus about it, but as you [say yourself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236559/disable-the-default-tab-key-behavior-in-chat#comment775545_236559), tab is a pretty obvious choice.

Comment: Given that pressing Enter in the textarea will automatically "submit" and effectively press the send button. Can we at least have a single TAB press to skip the send button, so that it isn't pressed and sends the incomplete message?

Answer (score 3):

I *actually rely on the tab key to work*, and do **not** want this to be removed.

When I want to upload an image, I use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to navigate to the *upload...* button and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. I really don't find it that hard to distinguish between autocompletion and tabbing to other elements of the web UI.

Moreover, [visually impaired people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235120/code-formatting-with-stack-overflow-programmers-and-code-review) use this site too and their screen readers rely heavily on things like <kbd>TAB</kbd> working. Removing this functionality will break chat for them in ways that may be hard to remedy.